# How to reverse the word after getting a Capital letter at the end of the word in JAVA?

Tags: java, arrays, string, reverse

Suppose you have a String and a CAPITAL letter in that indicates ending of a word. For example, if you have wElovEcakE where E, E and K indicates end of the words wE, lovE and cakE respectively. You need to reverse each word (as you know where it ends). Don’t reverse the String as a whole. To illustrate, if we give wElovEcakE as input output should be EwEvolEkac.  See wE became Ew, lovE became Evol and so on....

And the way i tried to approach with ..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Alternative {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner robo=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter  a word ");
        String word=robo.nextLine();
        char[] array=word.toCharArray();
        for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
            int count =0;
            for(int j=0;j<=("EMPTY");j++)  // here i am trying to operate a loop where it will work up to the Capital letter.
                count ++; 
            }
 //Code incomplete
        }
    }
}
```

Above i have mentioned "EMPTY" in the condition part ... i want to operate a loop where my loop will work up to the capital letter , then  i will count all the letter that i have counted up to capital letter then last step will be like i will make another loop where i will reverse all the letter where condition for the loop will <=count ;Example:lovE (counted 4 letters i will reverse four times back).

Can you guys help me to write the condition at "EMPTY" part if you think that my approach is correct ..
Can you guys help me to solve the problem in any other way ?

Comment: `j < array.length && array[j] is not uppercase` or such.

Comment: @JoopEggen can you write the code for the condition please ? yeah i know what you mean but i am getting error every time ...

Comment: Sorry I did not give a full answer as this seems homework, a tutorial excercise, though the Character class has useful functions for testing uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that makes use of the StringBuilder class to hold and reverse each found word.

```
Scanner robo = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a word:");
String word = robo.nextLine();
robo.close();
String upperCase = word.toUpperCase(); //used to find uppercase letters

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    char nextChar = word.charAt(i);
    builder.append(nextChar);
    if (nextChar == upperCase.charAt(i)) {
        String subWord = builder.reverse().toString();
        System.out.print(subWord); //It's not clear what to do with the found words
        builder = new StringBuilder();
    }
}
System.out.println();
```

Example

> Enter a word:
>   makEmorEpiE
>   EkamEromEip

Comment: i have mentioned it that i will reverse the word counted times back ward ..

Comment: @HelloWorld Sorry I don't understand what you mean but I have modified the code (print) slightly so it will output one word as expected

Answer (score 0):

test if this works for you:

```
Scanner robo = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.println("Enter  a word ");
String word = robo.nextLine();
String textInvert = "";
int indexAnt = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(i))) {
        String wordSplit = word.substring(indexAnt, i + 1);
        for (int j = wordSplit.length() - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            textInvert += wordSplit.charAt(j);
        indexAnt = i + 1;
    }
}
System.out.println(textInvert);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Alternative {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner robo = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter  a word ");
    String word = robo.nextLine();
    char[] array = word.toCharArray();
    int count = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        if (Character.isUpperCase(array[i])) { //find the upper case letters in the word
            for (int j = i; j > count; j--) //loop through the letters until the last count variable value is encountered
                System.out.print(array[j]); //print the reversed values
            count = i; //assign the last encountered uppercase letter's index value to count variable
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the question code only answers are discouraged. Please add a short explanation of the code and how it solves the issue.

Comment: @HelloWorld You're welcome. If u think at as a answer pls mark it as answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thank you for your suggestion. I have added explanation in the code

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with Regex pattern

```
    String[] in = "wElovEcakE".replaceAll("([A-z]+?[A-Z])","$1,").replaceAll(",$","").split(",");
    String out = "";
    for(String current: in){
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(); 
        temp.append(current);
        out+=temp.reverse();
    }
    System.out.println(out);
```

Result:

```
EwEvolEkac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```java
String textInvert = "wElovEcakE";
String revertText = textInvert
      .chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
      .reduce(new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(new StringBuilder())), (a, v) -> {
          a.getLast().append(v);
          if (Character.isUpperCase(v)) {
              a.add(new StringBuilder());
          }
          return a;
      }, (a1, a2) -> a1)
      .stream()
      .map(s -> s.reverse())
      .reduce(StringBuilder::append)
      .map(StringBuilder::toString)
      .get();

System.out.println(revertText);
```